# Why is my json request erroring instead of succeeding?

Tags: ajax, json, coldfusion

Here is my debugging method that goes to the error block instead of the success block.

```
function removerelationship(reference_related_id_var) {
            if ($('##relationships').attr('id') != undefined) {
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.cfm?action=reference.confirmjson',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {reference_id:reference_id_var, reference_related_id:reference_related_id_var},
                    success: function(){alert("I PASSED");},
                    error: function(){alert("I FAILED");}
                    });
```

But this is my response from calling reference.confirmjson:

```
{"MESSAGE":"Are You Sure You Want To Remove The Relationship Between References 744094 and 1200?","CONFIRMED":true}
```

Is there some reason this would still take me to the error block?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `if ($('##relationships')` a typo? That's not valid.

Comment: Are you actually seeing that response in Firebug or similar tool? Are you sure there is no leading whitespace in your response? Also, why are you passing data both in the `url` property as a query string, and in the `data` property?

Comment: I think he put the JS inside a `<cfoutput>` so he needs to escape "#" with "##"

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough information to answer this question. Based on your "response" the AJAX call is being properly sent to the server, received by the server and a valid response being returned by the server. This issue looks like the server side code is expecting some confirmation from you. You may not be using the API correctly.

Comment: @dmackerman - yea that's just to escape it

Comment: @JAAulde - that's actually my 100% HTTP response which is what is confusing me, that's the response I get from the server when I GET index.cfm?action=reference.confirmjson

Comment: Can you post your JSON response? The easiest way to debug is throw your JSON response into jsonlint.com. Also, make sure you have debug output turned off for the AJAX request `<cfsetting showDebugOutput= "false" />`. I explain it a bit better at http://orangexception.com/post/7308110027/remove-debug-output-from-ajax-requests-in-coldfusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have debug output turned off for the AJAX request . I explain it a bit better at http://orangexception.com/post/7308110027/remove-debug-output-from-ajax-requests-in-coldfusion

Comment: Many thanks, that was the issue and I like the way you handled it vs my just putting it at the beginning of my JSON file.

Comment: Be sure to check the github code. I changed where I do the headers now due to CFC requests.

Answer (score 2):

The error case would be called if any status other than a 200 is being returned.  Take a peek at the response in Firebug or a similar tool.  If CF is also throwing an error further down the request, it would return a 500.  This can help you determine if you need to check the CF application log for an error.

Edit: Also, check the raw response.  Firebug does an awesome job at dropping the trailing CF error and just showing the properly formatted JSON, which could be confusing if an error was thrown.

Comment: It's throwing a 200 status even which is even more confusing.

I wonder if it could be because I have CF debugging enabled? The raw response is just what I posted above in curly braces followed by the cfdebug output.